# Weak* and Strong type product convergence in the space of Radon measures

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Let $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ denote the space of all Lebesgue integrale functions and $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R})$ be the space of Radon measures which is the dual of continuous function with compact support on $\mathbb{R}.$
Do we have the following weak*-strong type convergence result.

**Let $\{f_n\} \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ be a sequence of functions

and $\mu_f\in \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R})$ with $f_n\buildrel\ast\over\rightharpoonup \mu_f$ in the weak$^*$ topology of $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R})$ and $g_n \rightarrow g$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R}).$ Suppose $g_n \leq K,$ does it imply $f_ng_n \buildrel\ast\over\rightharpoonup g\mu_f$ in $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}).$**

P.S:
$g\mu_f$ being the product of a radon measure and an $L^1$ function is also a radon measure.

Comment: Does $g_n\to g$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R},\mu_f)$ ? Then a basic triangle inequality should do the job.

Comment: I think this question could be drastically improved

Comment: It is not clear what this question is asking. What are the measures $f_n$? Are these $f_n d\mu$ where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure? $g_n$ converges to $g$ in $L^1$ with respect to what measure?

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the question.

Comment: I still am not sure that I understand the question, but if I understand it right, take $g_n(x) = 1_{\{|x| \leq 1\}}(x) - 1_{\{|x| \leq \frac{1}{n}\}}(x)$ and let $f_n(x) = n 1_{\{|x| <1/n\}}$. Then the measure corresponding to $f_n$ converges to $\delta_0$, $g_n$ converges to $1_{\{|x|\leq 1\}}$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $f_ng_n$ is identically zero. One also needs to be careful here about definitions. You cannot work with general Lebesgue measurable functions, since those only make sense up to Lebesgue null sets; there is no reason that $g \mu_f$ would even be well-defined for general $\mu_f$